# Mongoose instance methods. Results in Type error. Method not found

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The user model

````
```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const validator = require('validator');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    username: {
      type: String,
      unique: [true, 'Username already taken'],
      required: [true, 'Please enter a usernam']
    },
    dob: String,
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'Please provide your email'],
      unique: true,
      lowercase: true,
      validate: [validator.isEmail, 'Please provide with a mail']
    },
    profile_img: String, //url of the image   |||Should think how we have store the image|||
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'Please provide with a password'],
      minlength: 8,
      select: false
    },
    passwordConfirm: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'Please confirm your password'],
      validate: {
        validator: function(el) {
          return el === this.password;
        },
        message: "Password don't match"
      }
    },
    passwordChangedAt: Date,
    passwordResetToken: String,
    passwordResetExpires: Date,
    areaOfInterest: [], //array of String
    friends: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
      }
    ],
    isBoarded: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    createdAt: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now()
    }
  },
  {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true }
  }
);
//virtual populate
UserSchema.virtual('posts', {
  ref: 'Post',
  foreignField: 'userId',
  localField: '_id'
});
UserSchema.pre('save', async function(next) {
  if (!this.isModified('password')) return next();
  this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 12);
  this.passwordConfirm = undefined;
  next();
});

UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  if (!this.isModified('password') || this.isNew) return next();
  this.passwordChangedAt = Date.now() - 1000;
  next();
});

UserSchema.methods.correctPassword = async function(passwordToMatch, password) {
  return await bcrypt.compare(passwordToMatch, password);
};

UserSchema.methods.changedPasswordAfter = function(JWTTimeStamp) {
  if (this.passwordChangedAt) {
    const changedTimeStamp = parseInt(
      this.passwordChangedAt.getTime() / 1000,
      10
    );
    return JWTTimeStamp < changedTimeStamp;
  }

  return false;
};
````

This is where the method is added using the methods property before the exporting the model

```
UserSchema.methods.createPasswordResetToken = function() {
  const resetToken = crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('hex');

  this.passwordResetToken = crypto
    .createHash('sha256')
    .update(resetToken)
    .digest('hex');

  // console.log({ resetToken }, this.passwordResetToken);

  this.passwordResetExpires = Date.now() + 10 * 60 * 1000;

  return resetToken;
};

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

And method is called in this fuction

```
const { promisify } = require('util');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const User = require('../models/userModel');
const catchAsync = require('../utils/catchAsync');
const AppError = require('../utils/appError');
const sendEmail = require('../utils/email');

exports.forgotPassword =async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(User.schema.methods);
  const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
  console.log(user);
  if (!user) {
    return next(new AppError('No user with that email address', 404));
  }
```

Here is where the error occurs where I have called the method with the error "user.createPassswordResetToken is not a function","stack":"TypeError: user.createPassswordResetToken is not a function\n    at  controllers/authController.js:117:27\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)"
In the above mentioned error this is the line no which it points to

```
const resetToken = user.createPassswordResetToken();       
  await user.save({ validateBeforeSave: false });

  const resetURL = `${req.protocol}://${req.get(
    'host'
  )}/api/v1/users/resetPassword/${resetToken}`;

  const message = `Forgot your Password? Submit your new password and confirm your password at ${resetURL}.\n If you didn't forgot your password, please ignore this email.`;
```

```
The console log of User.schema.methods is
{
  correctPassword: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
  changedPasswordAfter: [Function (anonymous)],
  createPasswordResetToken: [Function (anonymous)]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the method in user schema is `createPasswordResetToken`, while in the function you called another non existing function `createPassswordResetToken`

use `createPasswordResetToken` rather than `createPassswordResetToken`